# Chaining a star sign in Ansible playbook

Tags: yaml, ansible

Lately, I've started to use Ansible, and i need some help with a playbook.
I'm trying to get a device details as a parameter, and then chain a star sign for it, in order to run a shell command. For example, if the device is `/etc/sda`
, the shell command will be `ls -l /dev/sda*`.

```
  - name: Get Hitachi Devices device details
    shell: lsscsi | grep HITACHI | awk '{print $6}'
    register: hitachiDevice

  - name: Check if the volume is partitioned
    shell: ls -l "{{ hitachiDevice.rc }}"* | wc -l
    failed_when: hitachiDevice.rc != 1
```

Here is the error i get after running the script:

```
{
  "changed": true,
  "cmd": "ls -l \"0\"* | wc -l",
  "delta": "0:00:00.027338",
  "end": "2016-08-10 14:15:12.200415",
  "failed": true,
  "failed_when_result": true,
  "rc": 0,
  "start": "2016-08-10 14:15:12.173077",
  "stderr": "ls: cannot access 0*: No such file or directory",
  "stdout": "0",
  "stdout_lines": [
    "0"
  ],
  "warnings": []
}
```

Any one know what is the issue and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hitachiDevice.rc` contains result code of previous command.
I bet it is always `0` if `grep` is successful.
So you next command will almost always will be `ls -l 0* | wc -l` which gives you the error

> ls: cannot access 0*: No such file or directory

I think you need something like `hitachiDevice.stdout`, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I expect that the first command will give me a devices name (`/etc/sda`), and the second command should give me a list if partitions of the device (`/etc/sda, /etc/sda1, /etc/sda2`) and i just want to count lines of the output. If the lines count is not 0, then the playbook should stop with an error.

Comment: Please inspect the content of the variable with `- debug: var=hitachiDevice` after the first task – it is a complex variable, not just lines.

Comment: Done. I got `"stdout_lines": [
            "/dev/sdg"
        ]`

Comment: I changed `hitachiDevice.rc` to `hitachiDevice.stdout` and got: `{"changed": true, "cmd": "ls -l \"/dev/sdg\"* | wc -l", "delta": "0:00:00.010330", "end": "2016-08-10 17:35:34.819617", "failed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "rc": 0, "start": "2016-08-10 17:35:34.809287", "stderr": "", "stdout": "1", "stdout_lines": ["1"], "warnings": []}`. It's seems that there is an issue with chaining the star sign to the volume name.

Comment: Remove quotes from `"{{hitachiDevice.stdout}}"` and put them around all command line, like this: `shell: "ls -l {{ hitachiDevice.stdout }}* | wc -l"`